# When I try to visit specific routes in my app by entering them directly into the browser url, I get a "Cannot GET '/exampleRouteName'" message

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a feeling that I'm misusing browserHistory or there is something wrong with my routes.jsx file. browserHistory is something has eluded me in exactly what it does in a React application. Equally, I may be completely off the mark by suggesting that it's a browserHistory issue. I will post my routes.jsx file and my ReactDOM.render from index.jsx to show you where I am feeding my Provider component browserHistory as a property.

**routes.jsx**

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="inventory" component={RequireAuth(Inventory)} />
        <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="single-product/:id" component={RequireAuth(Product)} />
        <Route path="examples" component={Examples} />
        <Route path="pricing" component={Pricing} />
        <Route path="profile" component={RequireAuth(Profile)} />
        <Route path="allProducts" component={RequireAuth(AllProducts)} />
        <Route path="reporting" component={RequireAuth(Reporting)} />
        <Route path="signout" component={Signout} />

        <Route path="tour" component={Tour}>
            <Route path="/business-types" component={BusinessTypes} />
            <Route path="/customers" component={Customers} />
            <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
            <Route path="/getting-started" component={GettingStarted} />
            <Route path="/multi-store" component={MultiStore} />
            <Route path="/support" component={Support} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
);
```

**Render Application in index.jsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.masterContainer'));
```

You'll see that some of my routes are wrapped in a HOC called RequireAuth, but this isn't causing the issue, it should handle an unauthenticated user trying to visit a route by kicking them back to the '/signup' route. To reiterate, if I went to my browser url and typed in 'localhost:3000/signup' it just shows me a " " Cannot GET '/signup' "

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely common issue people have with react-router, and yes you are correct it's an issue with browserHistory.

If you're using webpack you need to configure your webpack server to default all GET requests to '/' using a thing called historyApiFallback.

I recommend running through this very fast and very informative tutorial to save yourself future confusion with react-router:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial

Here's the info regarding browserHistory and preventing this very issue you're experiencing:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls

Essentially SPA's have handled client routing by putting a '#' in the URL allowing it to update the URL (to the right of the #) without the browser sending a GET request. browserHistory does not use the # so you need to use other means to prevent the GET request when you refresh the page or navigate directly to a URL.

You have a few options

1. add `--history-api-fallback` to your webpack npm script so it may look something like this:
   `"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback"`
2. Add some configuration to your webpack server like this:

   devServer: {
       historyApiFallback: true,
       contentBase: './'
   }
3. use hashHistory and you don't need to worry about it at all, but you have an ugly # in your URL

Comment: If am using an express server, will --history-api-fallback work the same way in my start script?